# Geometric Series Question Given Sum of First 2 and First 3 Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The sum of the first two terms of a convergent geometric series is 8 and the sum of the
first three terms is 26. What is the sum of the series?

---

I get to $ar^2 = 18$, $r = \sqrt{18/a}$ and then I sub it back into $a + ar = 8$ but I can't reduce it just for $a$ for some reason.

Comment: If the first term is $a$ and the common ratio is $r$, the sum of the first two terms is $a+ar$, of the first three terms is $a+ar+ar^2$. From here, you can find $a$ and $r$.

Comment: It would help to know what you have tried. Then one could deal with what stopped you from finishing.

Comment: I get to ar^2 = 18, r = sqrt(18/a) and then I sub it back into a + ar = 8 but I can't reduce it just for a for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If you take the ratio $c$ of the 3rd term divided by the 2nd term, you will get

$$(1 + r + r^2) = (1+r)c$$

which gives you a quadratic in $r$ that you can solve. Once you know $r$, then you can solve for $a$ using the 2nd term.